# Page loading takes so much time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using gmaps4rails gem to display different locations in google map. I have nearly 15000 records to display but it takes nearly 10 seconds to load the page. Here is my code to convert the given records into gmaps4rails objects:

```
@json = AlphaCourses.find(:all,:id,:latitude,:longitude).to_gmaps4rails
```

Can any one help me to load the page early.

Thanks

Comment: Did you follow instructions in the gem's [README](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/README.rdoc)? The mostly tiny place is scripts loading. Put them in the footer.

Comment: Please verify if the problem actually is your query, which you'll be able to see in the rails server console.

Comment: Hope that @apneadiving see your problem, he is the author of gmap4rails and is very active in SO.

Comment: yup it shows some thing like EXPLAIN for: SELECT id,latitude,longitude FROM `alpha_courses`and there is no possible keys.I am using id as a primary key.

Completed 200 OK in 5701ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 7.2ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Caching Strategies. Awesome tutorial on [caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/89-page-caching) available in RailsCasts. And also [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html). Thanks.